# How can I detect if I havn't created a NotificationChannel for the notification I am posting, except for the log?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I'm building an infrastructure for notifications on Android, once I've created a NotificationChannel it seems that the channel persists while my app is being killed and restarted, over and over again, through compilations, installs, and force-stops.

When do NotificationChannels die? Only on device restart?

I have created a channel in my code like this:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            return;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.setDescription(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel); // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance or other notification behaviors after this
    }
```

**Then, I removed the channel-creation code**, recompiled and reinstalled, and used evaluate-expression to see if the channel I created exists, like this:

```
mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel("NotificationChannelId") != null
```

**...And the channel still exists!** My problem is, that after I recompiled and reinstalled, the channel persisted and still exists, and I can't raise a runtime-exception for my client developer, because I can't detect correctly when a channel is not created.
I have made sure that my apk is built and installed with all its changes(said changes were not creating the channel) but the channel still exists.

How can I detect that a channel wasn't created if the channel persists even after the app dies?